# Form submit not working after second attempt in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-2

I have a form in my project that will be submitted by jQuery AJAX.

The data will be validated on the server side and if the data is invalid it will load the *form* with validation errors and append that HTML to the div.

On the next form submission attempt, it is directly redirected to the form action URL, i.e. 
`event.preventDefault()` is not working.

Here is my code:

```
initFormSubmit: function () {
                var form = $('form#forum');
                $(document).on('submit', form, function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    if ($(this).attr('name')) {
                        form.append(
                                $("<input type='hidden'>").attr({
                            name: $(this).attr('name'),
                            value: $(this).attr('value')})
                                );
                    }

                    var formData = form.serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: form.attr('method'),
                        url: form.attr('action'),
                        data: formData,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#respond').empty();

                            $('#respond').append(data);
                        }
                    });
                });

            }
```

data = form with validation error if invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using event delegation correctly. The second parameter you're passing to [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is `form`, which is a jQuery object.

For event delegation, the second parameter needs to be a string. Since it is an object, jQuery is assuming that it is meant to be passed in as the `data` parameter instead of the `selector` parameter. (If you do `console.log(event.data)` inside the handler, it should show the form object).

Simply change the handler to:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#forum', function (event) {
```

and make sure to change all the references inside the handler from `form` to `$(this)`

Comment: The only thing i have done made it work is, load the js file that contains the code above with the appended html. But its not a good practice i thinks

Comment: Maybe I'm focusing on the wrong issue altogether then. What is `initFormSubmit`. Can you provide more context in the question?

Comment: it is a jquery plugin helper

Comment: @BijeshShrestha You should add the pastebin to the question. If more people see it they might be able to help.

Comment: ok it worked after i cleared the browser's cache ;) and recall the helper after success

Answer (score 0):

Try using `event.preventDefault` at the end of the submit event like this:

```
$(document).on('submit', form, function (event) {

                if ($(this).attr('name')) {
                    form.append(
                            $("<input type='hidden'>").attr({
                        name: $(this).attr('name'),
                        value: $(this).attr('value')})
                            );
                            event.preventDefault();
                }
           **}**
```